# Mocking some calls and do not mock some call in same spring service method

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I need to write test for my `spring` service.
I have to mock some calls in my service method and some calls have to work normally.

Means, my service method is

```
myInjectingService.submit()
```

inside that method in service the things to be mocked are

```
myMockService.createSomething(.....)
myMockService.verifyP(.)
```

Things need not to be mocked are saving the value to database.
So in service, repository will be autowired and will save it.

My problem is mocking is not working.
Is it possible to mock something and do not something together

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/context.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class Test {
    @Mock
    public MyMockService myMockService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Throwable {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);        
    }

    @InjectMocks
    private MyInjectingService myInjectingService;

    @Autowired private Repository1 repository1; 
    @Autowired private Repository2 repository2;

    static {
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "test");
    }

    private void saveTestData() {
        //create entity objects
        Entity1 e1 = new Entity1();
        //set attributes

        //create entity objects
        Entity2 e2 = new Entity2();
        //set attributes

        //save entity objects
        repository1.save(e1);
        repository2.save(e2);
    }

    @Test
    public void submitTest() {
        saveData();     

        P p= new P();
        Mockito.when(myMockService.createSomething(Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(),Mockito.any())).thenReturn(p);
        Mockito.when(myMockService.verifyP(p)).thenReturn(1);

        Response res = myInjectingService.submit();
        assertNotNull(res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [@Spy](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Spy.html) and [doCallRealMethod()](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/073795f888f0eeb7e93710ccbedfc8a25c5b7949/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doCallRealMethod())

```
@Spy 
private Repository1 repository1; 
@Before
public void setUp() throws Throwable {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);        
}
```

Stubbing will look like this:

```
doCallRealMethod().when(repository1).doSomething1(); //real method will be called
when(repository1.doSoemthing2()).thenReturn(somethingToReturn); //will return somethingToReturn
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is unit test then you dont have to ( or even should not ) save values to database. What you can do instead is just mocking repositories so they 'doNothing' while saving, but may 'doReturn' when 'find' method is used. The thing here is that you should test one thing at a time - just 'MyInjectingService' method, mock its dependencies and test them in other places if needed ( avoid testing for example spring repositories, hibernate core methods etc ).

If you really need some nasty way to call original method then check [doCallRealMethod](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12). But I believe its not needed in your code.